# Count maximum amount of values within a time sample in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
ID           time
A1      2019-04-04 08:04:56 
A11     2019-04-04 08:14:22 
BB      2019-04-04 08:44:53
C5      2019-04-04 09:01:12
C1      2019-04-04 09:03:51
DD      2019-04-04 10:02:42
```

So, i want to get maximum of numbers of ID within a sample of "time" of 20 minutes. So here we get 2 unique ID (2019-04-04 08:04:56 and 2019-04-04 08:14:22), 3 unique ID (2019-04-04 08:44:53,  2019-04-04 09:01:12, 2019-04-04 09:03:51) and 1 unique ID (2019-04-04 10:02:42). max(2,3,1)=3. So the answer is 3. How could i get it? Desired result is to get it as dataframe:

```
time                    ID_num
2019-04-04 08:04:56        2
2019-04-04 08:44:53        3
2019-04-04 10:02:42        1
```

I can define my sampling array like this:

```
numpy.arange(8, 20, 0.3)
```

that is, going from 8am to 8pm with 0.3-hour increment

Comment: Hi, do you really want to get 3 lines as an output or are you just interested in the maximum, which is 3? If you are interested in 3 lines, could you please describe, how you get these three lines? do you want to get the maximum nuber of samples within an arbitrary period of 20 minutes or are the periods fixed like 8:00-8:20, 8:20-8:40, ...?

Comment: You could  improve the clarity of the question by indicating if your "increments" are 20 minute partitions of time (non overlapping)  is so what determine a start; fixed point in time or first sample.  if it is instead a sliding window what constitutes a step smallest given change in time (second) or next given sample ... it is a guessing game till you get specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Lets define some groups based on time differences

s=((df.time.diff(1) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm') >=20)|(df.time.diff(1).isna())).cumsum()

#Now let us groupby as we pick the first occurrence of time in a group and find how many ids are in each group using .groupby() and agg()

    df.groupby(s).agg(ftime=('time','first'), idcount=('ID','count'))



                 ftime      idcount
        time                             
1    2019-04-04 08:04:56        2
2    2019-04-04 08:44:53        3
3    2019-04-04 10:02:42        1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the "times", offset each by 20 minutes and slice the dataframe to check the length of a subset. Then get the max of each of those subsets.

```
df= df.set_index("time")
offset = pd.Timedelta("20min")

lengths = []
for start_time in df.index:
    stop_time = start_time + offset
    chunk_length = df.loc[start_time:stop_time].shape[0]
    
    record = (start_time, chunk_length)
    lengths.append(record)
    
max(lengths, key=lambda item: item[1])
(Timestamp('2019-04-04 08:44:53'), 3)
```

The output indicates that the timestamp 2019-04-04 08:44:53 had 3 records in the dataframe that existed between that timestamp and 20minutes after that timestamp. Thus giving you the max consecutive length, as well as the timestamp where the consecutive run began.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the 20-minute period with the most samples in it, where the 20-minute-period is freely definable, you can do it as follows:

```
from datetime import timedelta

df= pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        ID=['A1', 'A11', 'BB', 'C5', 'C1', 'DD'],
        time=pd.to_datetime(['2019-04-04 08:04:56', '2019-04-04 08:14:22', '2019-04-04 08:44:53', '2019-04-04 09:01:12', '2019-04-04 09:03:51', '2019-04-04 10:02:42'])
    )
)
df.dtypes

previous_time= df['time'].shift(1)
previous_time= df['time'].where(previous_time.isnull(), previous_time)
df['fake']= (df['time'] > previous_time + timedelta(minutes=20)).cumsum()
df2= df.merge(df, on='fake', suffixes=('', '_next'))

df2.dtypes

indexer= df2['time_next'].between(df2['time'], df2['time'] + timedelta(minutes=20))
result= df2[indexer].groupby('time').agg(
    count=('time', 'count'), 
    period_start=('time_next', 'min'),
    last_sample_in_period=('time_next', 'max')
)

result.sort_values('count', ascending=False).iloc[0]
```

The last line outputs:

```
count                                      3
period_start             2019-04-04 08:44:53
last_sample_in_period    2019-04-04 09:03:51
Name: 2019-04-04 08:44:53, dtype: object
```

The same can also be achieved with this code:

```
from datetime import timedelta

df= pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        ID=['A1', 'A11', 'BB', 'C5', 'C1', 'DD'],
        time=pd.to_datetime(['2019-04-04 08:04:56', '2019-04-04 08:14:22', '2019-04-04 08:44:53', '2019-04-04 09:01:12', '2019-04-04 09:03:51', '2019-04-04 10:02:42'])
    )
)

df['period_end']= df['time'] + timedelta(minutes=20)
df['count']= 1
time_series=df['time']
continue_iteration= True
period_end_series= df['period_end']
while continue_iteration:
    time_series= time_series.shift(-1)
    in_period= (~time_series.isnull()) & (time_series <= period_end_series)
    df['count']+= in_period
    continue_iteration= in_period.any()
df.sort_values(by='count', ascending=False, inplace=True)
df.iloc[0]
```

The difference between the two ways is, that the first produces a subset of the cross product by joining the dataframe with itself. It is suitable for small data sets and datasets with a lot of gaps with more than 20 minutes and a not so large number of maximum samples within a 20 minutes period.
The second does not need to join the dataframe with itself. It just shifts the time column as long as there is at least one match with the period. So if `m` denotes the maximum number of samples within an arbitary 20-minute-period within the dataframe, then the loop terminates exactly after `m` shift operations (because of the stop criterium `in_period.any()`)